# SQL command not properly ended with select

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working with Oracle SQL Developer with a Java application. I want to ask to the DB this query:

```
select * from vocabolario, vocaboli_help where verbo=1 and 
 vocabolario.id = vocaboli_help.id and vocaboli_help.usato = 0
```

The query works when I run it from SQL developer, but when run it from Eclipse with the `stmt.executeQuery(string)`, where stmt is a Statement object, it throws the following exception: SQL command not properly ended.
I put also a semicolon at the end of the string, but it doesn't work.

I used the `stmt.executeQuery(string)` with other queries and in those cases there were no problems. The only difference I can see is that in this case I have `where` condition in `AND`.

Java code :

```
private final static String NOME_DATABASE = "VOCABOLARIO", NOME_DATABASE_HELP ="VOCABOLI_HELP";
String type ="verbo";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + NOME_DATABASE + ", " + NOME_DATABASE_HELP +" WHERE " + type + " = 1 " +
                "AND " + NOME_DATABASE +".ID = " + NOME_DATABASE_HELP +".ID AND "+NOME_DATABASE_HELP+".USATO = 0";
    System.out.println(query);
    int cont = 0; 
    String result=""; 
    try {
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(res.next()) {
            String cod = res.getString("ID").trim();
            String voc = res.getString("VOCABOLO").trim();
            String trad = res.getString("TRADUZIONE").trim();

            if(cont == n)
                result = cod + "," + voc + "," + trad;

            cont++; 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

`

Comment: Post the Java code you are executing.

Comment: in your sql code you reference table `vocabolario_help` but in java it's `vocaboli_help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, the problem was in the name of the second table, but I think it depends on Java code sintax, as @are suggested.
I updated the code:

```
private static final String NOME_DATABASE_HELP = "VOCABOLIHELP"
```

I also modified the table name in the DB and now it works. I think there are issues with the underscore in the name (the problem is only in Java as I said), I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from vocabolario vo
left join vocaboli_help voh
on vo.id= voh.id
where v.verbo=1 AND voh.usato=0
```

You just need a simple join.

VOCABOLI_HELP or vocabolario_help  your code and your post different

Comment: There is already a "simple" join in the query - although it's using the ancient, outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: The query works on SQL developer, but not in the Java application, I don't think that is a problem in the query itself but how I wrote it in Java. I posted the Java code.

Comment: @user2993413 vocaboli or vocabolario are you sure about it? It seems you have used different syntax.

Comment: "vocaboli_help" and "vocabolario" are two different tables in my database.

Comment: no, check your post at top select ....  vocabolario_help and checkjava code NOME_DATABASE_HELP ="VOCABOLI_HELP" vocabolario_help!=vocaboli_help

Comment: I think there's a language issue :) vocabolario means vocabulary, vocaboli means words. NOME_DATABASE_HELP is not an helper for NOME_DATABASE, they are two different tables in the database and both have the field ID, so for the join condition they must be equal.<br>NOME_DATABASE_HELP is not a checkjava code (if you mean it helps to find mistakes).

Comment: it's not language - you have 2 different table names in java code and sql code. sql works and have no syntax problem, but java code doesn't... the 1st that should be checked is the names...

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood before.. Now I've tried to do a simple query with the table VOCABOLI_HELP, and it doesn't work. Is the "_" in the name the problem?